# How to set xinput DualPoint stick speed in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, hardware, touchpad, xinput, ubuntu-18.04

I need to optimize the speed of my point stick since I installed Xubuntu 18.04.
When I run xinput list-props 15, here is what I get:

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick':
Device Enabled (143):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (280):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (281):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (282):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (283):   0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (284):   0, 0, 1
libinput Button Scrolling Button (285): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (286): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (287):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (288):    0
libinput Accel Speed (289): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (290): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (291):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (292):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (293):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (265): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (266):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (267):    0, 0
Device Node (268):  "/dev/input/event6"
Device Product ID (269):    2, 8
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (296):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (297):   1
```

I don't see any prop that corresponds to the speed. Is there another solution to adapt the speed of point stick?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

For my touchpad modifying the `Coordinate Transformation Matrix` helped, I set it to `2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000` which sped up my pointer quite a bit.

Your command should read like this in the end:

```
input set-prop 15 145 \
2.400000, 0.000000, 0.000000, \
0.000000, 2.400000, 0.000000, \
0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

You can fiddle around with the two first values in the diagonal to adjust to your needs.

Comment: This works for me! Is it documented somewhere what these values represents? Seems like a three dimentional transformation matrix, but what's the third dimension for? EDIT: it seems to be a multiplier inversely proposal to the speed. So setting the last coordinate to 2 has the same effect as setting the x and y values to 0.5.